# How to repeat sound effect while MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I tried to set the `setLooping` to true, without any result. I would want the sound effect to repeat while event is detected, and when released, to stop repeat.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  MediaPlayer player;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rifle);
    player.setLooping(true);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      int ey = (int) event.getY();
      if (ey > height / 2) {
        player.start();
      }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
  // start music
}
else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
  // stop music
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it seems that implementing this, causes sound effects to get queued; so while pressing screen about 5 secs, the sound repeats about 15 minutes eventhough I don't press the screen anymore. What I'm trying to accomplish, is that when pressing the screen, the sound repeats rapidly (like gunfire), and when I stop touching the screen, it plays the currently playing sound effect to its end, and stops.

Comment: try to use setOnCompletionListener method on your player, there you can tell your player what to do, when actual sound finishes: to start playing sound again, or to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not prepare the player.

You are not allowed to call start on an unprepared player.